# Как собрать массив объектов из mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Есть запрос: `SELECT * FROM products`. Есть `mysqli_result`. Как собрать массив объектов класса `Product.php`?

Я читал в мануале и не нашел ответа, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: @splash58 вы из фразы "массив объектов класса" только первое слово прочитали? )

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8mb4");

$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$products = [];
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object("Product")) {
    $products = $obj;
}
```

Но это работает только если все свойства класса Product публичные и их имена совпадают с именами колонок в таблице. В реальной жизни редко бывает так, и надо явно передавать все значения в конструктор

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[] = new Product($row["name"], $row["price"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответ, разрбрался. Взял по строке из каждого ассоциативного массива и подставил в новый объект. Пришел из Java, так что разбираюсь пока :)

```
public function getAllProducts(): array
{
    $productList = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

    $queryResult = $this->executeQuery($sql);

    foreach ($queryResult as $row){
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setSku($row["sku"]);
        $product->setAttribute($row["attribute"]);
        $product->setPrice($row["price"]);
        $product->setName($row["name"]);
        $product->setType($row["type"]);

        array_push($productList, $product);
    }

    return $productList;
}
```

Comment: а вы MongoDB используете ?